# How do you conditionally format dataframe objects?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to conditionally format these precinct names depending on whether the ward comes up as "0" or not but I keep running into object type issues because they dataframe objects and not vectors. I have tried using if_else and case_when but keep running into errors. What should I be using to format these? This is my code for reference

```
glimpse(albany_precincts_2023)

##trying case_when##

albany_precincts_2023 <- albany_precincts_2023 %>%
case_when(ward == 0 ~ mutate(precinct_name = paste(town_city, election_dist, sep = "-")))

##trying if_else##

       albany_precincts_2023 <- albany_precincts_2023 %>%
if_else(ward != 0, 
      mutate(precinct_name = paste(town_city, election_dist, sep = "-")),
      mutate(precinct_name = paste(town_city, ward, election_dist, sep = "-")))
```

This is also a glimpse of the structure of the data for referrence

```
  $ town_city  <chr> "ALBANY", "ALBANY", "ALBANY", "ALBANY", "ALBANY", "ALBANY", 
  "ALBANY", "ALBANY"
  $ ward                    <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
  2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3…
$ election_dist           <int> 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5…
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mutate` incorrectly.

Your code should be like (not tested):

```
library(dplyr)
albany_precincts_2023 %>%
  mutate(precinct_name = if_else(!ward, 
                                 paste(town_city, election_dist, sep = "-"), 
                                 paste(town_city, ward, election_dist, sep = "-")))
```

and for `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
albany_precincts_2023 %>%
  mutate(precinct_name = case_when(
    !ward ~ paste(town_city, election_dist, sep = "-"),
    .default = paste(town_city, ward, election_dist, sep = "-")
  ))
```

Comment: I am running into a different issue. So I also need to pad these districts with leading zeroes and have done so with str_pad. Unfortunately, when I try to apply the mutate after doing this I get this error: Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `precinct_name = if_else(...)`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• ward = "000"
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.